# Add div using ng-if with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I am trying to render the div with the ng-repeat when the $index == 2.
In this case the "France" index 2 will be shown. Any help will be appreciate it

```
$scope.Countries = [
{ Name : 'USA'},
{ Name : 'Japan'},
{ Name : 'France'},
{ Name : 'Canada'},
{ Name : 'China'},
];

<div ng-repeat="country in Countries>
<div class="col-md-2" ng-if="$index == 2">
<a href="">{{country.Name}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You just missed the quotation mark in `div` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not closing the ng-repeat div. Something that could also be an issue is the absence of [$track by index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

```
<div ng-repeat="country in Countries track by $index">
  <div class="col-md-2" ng-if="$index == 2">
    <a href="">{{ country.Name }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And the ng-repeat quote.

Comment: Its just the missing closing quote: http://plnkr.co/edit/A1RybDUIRLptiCXaLSJM?p=preview

Comment: You only need to track by index is there are repeats in the array, $index is still available if you are not tracking by index.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this? Why not just show index 2?

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
     <a href="">{{ Countries[2].Name }}</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I want something to happen when the index is 3 or another number, learning porpuses

Comment: @GilbertoQuintero probably more practical to set `activeItem` or similar property in controller than toggling by index

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="country in countries">
     <div class="col-md-2" ng-if="$index == 2">
         <a href="">{{country.Name}}</a>
     </div>
</div>
```